# Trying to get an Array passed in internal AjAX Call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am working on a form where I need to set the values of a dropdown selection based on a prior selection. This bit is ok and I set up an internal Ajax call to deal with this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hub').on('change', function(){
        var hubid = $("#hub").val();
        var hubtype = <?php echo json_encode($hub_types_list); ?>;
        console.log(hubid);
        console.log(hubtype);
        if(hubid){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                data: {ajax: 1,hub_id: hubid,hub_type: hubtype},
                success:function(html){
                    $('#firstrating').html(html);
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#firstrating').html('<option value="">Select Hub Airport first</option>');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

This bit is ok as when I run in a browser I can see in java console

[image: Console Logged Variables]

However when I process the AJAX CALL

```
// Handle AJAX request (start)
if( isset($_POST['ajax']) && isset($_POST['hub_id']) && isset($_POST['hub_type'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['hub_type'])){ 
        $typed = $_POST['hub_type'];
        $typed = json_decode($typed, true);
        echo '<option value="'.$_POST['ajax'].'">'.$_POST['ajax'].'</option>';
        echo '<option value="'.$_POST['hub_id'].'">'.$_POST['hub_id'].'</option>';
        echo '<option value="'.$_POST['hub_type'].'">'.$_POST['hub_type'].'</option>';
        echo '<option value="">Select Aircraft Type Rating</option>';
        foreach($typed as $typex){
            echo '<option value="'.$typex['LNKId'].'">'.$typex['LNKType'].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<option value="">Aircraft Type Rating not available</option>';
    }
    exit;
}
// Handle AJAX request (end)
```

All I get back in the options are as follows -:

[image: Returned Selections]

So from the returned data in the OPTIONS you can see that I got a '1' for the AJAX variable , EDDN for hub_id and Array for hub_type and a message 'Select Aircraft Type Rating.

The problem it seems is that I have in the $POST variables an array as I needed to look at which was posted by AJAX call but I cannot seem to get the array back into PHP format to then show as Options.  Obviously once fixed the console log and options to show $post variables will be removed.

Can anybody help with the method to get that array back into PHP for the section dealing with the AJAX call processing .  Many thanks

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Also knowing the difference between [tag:java] and [tag:javascript] will help ("*java console*")

Comment: `$_POST['hub_type']` is an array. You're just referring to `$_POST['hub_type']` directly in the echo. PHP doesn't know how you want an array to be displayed, it has no direct textual representation so it just gives up and writes the word "Array" instead. You need to give specific instructions for how to display it (e.g. by looping through the elements).

Comment: Also `$typed` won't be useful because `$_POST['hub_type']` isn't JSON, so it won't have decoded properly.

Comment: If in doubt! _Debug rule 1 of 1000_ Add a `print_r($_POST);` and see what has actually been passed, then you can attempt to either fix something or correctly process what is passed

Comment: Also...this whole thing is a bit bizarre. You already have a static list of data in the JavaScript in the `hub_type` variable which was taken directly from some data delivered from PHP in the previous request. Why don't you display that directly in the dropdown? All you're doing with the AJAX request is sending the same data back to PHP and then echoing it back in the form of some HTML options. You could do that in JavaScript directly and save your user and your server the bandwidth of the HTTP request. The AJAX request is not adding any value here, unless you've omitted something from the PHP

Comment: $_POST['hub_type']. should be JSON   as the ajax call set it up as a var with json encode  i.e. var hubtype = <?php echo json_encode($hub_types_list); ?>;

Comment: `should be JSON as the ajax call set it up as a var with json encode`...no, because it gets interpreted by JS as an object literal. It becomes code instead of JSON data, at that point. And then in $.ajax you're just sending it back with the default content-type which is form-url-encoded, so jQuery converts it to that format (e.g. `name=value&name2=value2`) etc when it sends the request. Look in your browser's Network tool as what it's actually sending in the AJAX. Plus the fact that echoing `$_POST['hub_type']` produces "Array" makes it clear it was never JSON to begin with.

Comment: `foreach($_POST['hub_type'] as $typex){ echo '<option value="'.$typex['LNKId'].'">'.$typex['LNKType'].'</option>'; }` would output the data you wanted, but it would be a lot more efficient to scrap the AJAX and just do this in JS. Also you say the purpose here is to `set the values of a dropdown selection based on a prior selection`, but there's no code here which does anything dependent on anything else. It just echoes a load of data you'd already pre-set, without any conditions. The whole thing seems to make very little sense TBH.

Comment: Yes there is some code missing at present but that comes when I get the array back I will filter the results of hub_type  depending on the value of hub_id.  So when I have a dropdown list of hub airports when selected it triggers the Ajax process and thus when I selected EDDN this is what you saw in the console log. In the Ajax process it clearly has received the $Post items so eventually I would read through the array and select only those values that matched hub_id

Comment: so the problem seems in the line.    var hubtype = <?php echo json_encode($hub_types_list); ?>;   is that the $_POST['hub_type']; says its an array because I asked for  $_POST['hub_type'] to be sent back as an option . I know this is wrong of course it was just a test to see if I had data there. So how do I get the data into the AJAX call as json data so that         $typed = $_POST['hub_type'];
        $typed = json_decode($typed, true);  will work

Comment: No it's not, I've told you how to fix it in my last comment

Comment: BUT... `when I get the array back I will filter the results of hub_type` ... a far more logical approach would be not to create `var hubtype` to begin with. Instead, wait until the user has selected a hub through the dropdown, and then just send hub_id (alone) to the AJAX. _Then_ get the list of items filtered by hub ID (presumably using SQL would be most efficient) and echo the resulting options.

Comment: `So how do I get the data into the AJAX call as json data so that $typed = $_POST['hub_type']; $typed = json_decode($typed, true); will work` ...you don't need to. I already showed you how to work with the array you've got (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71673795/trying-to-get-an-array-passed-in-internal-ajax-call#comment126670214_71673795). But it's irrelevant anyway - see my last comment for a more normal and efficient approach to the whole scenario.

Comment: The form is from a framework where database reads are done outside of this page script   The three lines        echo '<option value="'.$_POST['ajax'].'">'.$_POST['ajax'].'</option>';
        echo '<option value="'.$_POST['hub_id'].'">'.$_POST['hub_id'].'</option>';
        echo '<option value="'.$_POST['hub_type'].'">'.$_POST['hub_type'].'</option>'; were only there for testing as I was not getting any data back

Comment: `database reads are done outside of this page script`...well you can `include` any scripts containing the functions you need at any given time. A framework wouldn't provide a mechanism to handle AJAX requests (which are really no different than any other kind of request as far as the server is concerned) and then not also provide a mechanism for data access during such a request. Or maybe you've gone outside the framework structure and that's why you're struggling with that. We can't really tell obviously from the small code sample, and we don't know what framework it is.

Comment: @ADyson `it would be a lot more efficient to scrap the AJAX and just do this in JS` if you're suggesting doing the processing client side, that is bad practice. Server side is for processing, client side is for displaying. As for the issue, you're right, if you try to send non-string data via ajax, it will implicitly convert it to a string. It would seem `<?php echo json_encode($hub_types_list); ?>` is actually returning an array, not a json string. What does ` console.log(hubtype)` show?

Comment: @PoorlyWrittenCode why would that be bad practice? It's more efficient if the processing isn't onerous and would save on bandwidth and requests, which can slow a page down much more than some basic JS. But anyway I've gone back on that now having realised that the OP needn't have put the hub_type data in there to begin with, because they actually should be fetching and filtering it later in the process, during the AJAX request after the user has selected something to filter by.

Comment: @PoorlyWrittenCode `Server side is for processing, client side is for displaying.` is a gross oversimplification and actually quite an old-fashioned approach - look at all the proliferation of client-side UI frameworks which do significant client-side processing in order to manage the display, rather than just showing static content delivered by the server. If you mean data processing like filtering etc well at the point I made that comment no data processing was going on, the OP's code was just echoing static data into HTML elements, which could easily be client-side job. We've moved on tho.

Comment: I fixed it with three lines and it works !!!                                                           $typed = $_POST['hub_type'];
$type1 = json_encode($typed);
$test1 = json_decode($type1,true);

Comment: Hm, but surely it's obviously that there is no point in encoding something just to decode it again immediately afterwards. You're just reversing the process and you end up with identical data to what you started with. The code you've just provided in your comment is functionally identical to `$test1 = $_POST['hub_type'];`! You can just use the `foreach` loop I told you about 4 hours ago and that would solve your issue.

Comment: Step by step demo of what I mean regarding the redundant encoding and decoding process: https://3v4l.org/6udCr

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through `$_POST["hub_type"]` as that's a ready-made array containing what you need. Using `$typed` doesn't work because you tried to decode something which isn't JSON.

Full example:

```
if( isset($_POST['ajax']) && isset($_POST['hub_id']) && isset($_POST['hub_type'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['hub_type'])){ 
        echo '<option value="">Select Aircraft Type Rating</option>';
        foreach($_POST["hub_type"] as $typex){
            echo '<option value="'.$typex['LNKId'].'">'.$typex['LNKType'].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<option value="">Aircraft Type Rating not available</option>';
    }
    exit;
}
```

---

Having said that, the overall approach here is quite inefficient. A more logical approach would be not to create `var hubtype` to begin with. Instead, wait until the user has selected a hub through the dropdown, and then just send `hub_id` (alone) to the PHP script via AJAX. Then get the list of items filtered by hub ID (presumably using a SQL WHERE clause would be most efficient, assuming you store this data in a database) and then echo the resulting options.

This is much more efficient than outputting all the possible options to the client-side, then sending them back to the server, then filtering them with PHP and generating HTML to send back again.

Answer (score -1):

```
$typed = $_POST['hub_type'];
$type1 = json_encode($typed);
$test1 = json_decode($type1,true);
```

I fixed the problem by using these three lines , the others were used for testing what was being received in the $Post array.

This means that I can have dynamic dropdowns where one dropdown value will be used to filter the data for the second dropdown without leaving the form.